# Symfony2 Validating an optional field

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony, symfony-2.0

In my form, I have a field with required option set to false, this field is optional.

However, I would like to have a notBlank validation on this field when the field is used:

```
@Assert\NotBlank(
 *     message="The name field can't be blank",
 *     groups={"flow_poemDataCollector_step1"}
 * )
```

Right now, I can't use the validation constraint NotBlank because it will cause my form validation to fail when the field is unused.

I tried something to add a random value in the field in a onPostBindRequest listener, but it is complex and didn't manage to have it working. I'm not sure that it is the right way to proceed neither.

Here is what I tried:  ($form is a Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface object)

```
    $form = $event->getForm();
    $formData = $form->getData();
    $formData->setUserName("foo");
    $form = $form->setData($formData);
```

But then I get an error that I can't call isValid() on an unbound form.

How can I achieve my goal? ie. Validating the field only in some case.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but if someone uses the field, that automatically makes it not blank, right? Or are you trying to make a 'B' field notBlank when a 'A' field is used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way I can see to achieve this is to use a [Callback validator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html) on your entity. As this callback is defined in your entity, it has access to all properties. Through the ExecutionContext you can then set violations as needed.

Answer (score 10):

This is an old question, but it seems that now we can do it this way:

```
@Assert\Optional(
    @Assert\NotBlank(
        message="The name field can't be blank",
        groups={"flow_poemDataCollector_step1"}
    )
)
```

ref: http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/reference/constraints/Collection.html

Comment: The `Optional` constraint appears to only work on a `Collection`, and can't be used on a single field -- for example, if you have a field that is optional, but must be an email if it exists, then `Optional` does not appear to be useful.

Comment: If you need to validate more optional constraints you put them into array as an optional's constrainet parameter

Comment: Not sure what you're on about mate @simont. This is an actual solution since the Optional constrain was introduced in Symfony.  Whether you validate one field or entire form you pass them as a collection (collection of 1 item or multiple items respectively) to your validator.
Example of usage: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Collection.html#required-and-optional-field-constraints

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. I had to reread your question several times because something in it is not logically valid.

If you want the field to be not required then using the `NotBlank` constraint makes no sense. How can a field be not required and required at the same time?

If all you want is that if something is entered in that field doesn't  consist of just spaces, then you don't need the `NotBlank` constraint at all because Symfony trims the user input by default, so it will end up as if nothing has been entered at all.

Comment: OK Let me rephrase: the field can be required or not depending on previous user input. If field is required, then I want the NotBlank constraint.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the field to be optional, you can:

`new Assert\Length(array('min' => 0))`

because omitting the field from the constraint will cause an Unexpected field error.

Answer (score 0):

ended up here searching for how to make a field both optional and, if entered, validated, like an optional email:

from symfony docs:

> As with most of the other constraints, null and empty strings are
> considered valid values. This is to allow them to be optional values.
> If the value is mandatory, a common solution is to combine this
> constraint with NotBlank.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Email.html

so the solution is just to validate as `Email` and the field will still be optional.